# Задача о процессах

Tags: c, linux

Коллеги, хочу поделиться забавной задачей. Сколько новых процессов будет порождено в ходе выполнения данной программы и почему?

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (fork() && (i == 1))  break;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Боян от Бобука с Яндекса?

Comment: Чем бы не тешилось...

Comment: не понял ни хрена.

Comment: Цель данного вопроса -- проэкзаменовать отвечающих?

Comment: нет, развлечь )))

Comment: ну получилось

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пять. Исходный процесс порождает два, завершается с i==1, второй -- один, выход по i==1, третий и четвертый -- по одному, выход i==3. Пятый и шестой погибают бездетными. Исходный и пять новых

Comment: А кто удалил мой первый ответ?

Answer (score 2):

Хех, ну после рисования на бумажке получается 6 потоков)

1. Исходный поток1 порождает поток2
2. Проверяется условие в обоих потоках, ни в одном не выполняется
3. Поток1 порождает поток3.
4. Проверяется условие в потоке1, выполняется, поток завершается.
5. Проверяется условие в потоке3, не выполняется.
6. Поток3 порождает поток4.
7. Проверяется условие выхода из цикла в потоке4 и потоке3, не выполняются, потоки выходят из циклов и завершаются.
8. Тем временем поток2 времени даром не теряет. Порождает поток5.
9. Проверяется условие в потоке2, выполняется, поток завершается.
10. Поток5 порождает поток6.
11. Проверяются условия выхода из цикла в потоке5 и потоке6, не выполняются, потоки выходят из циклов и завершаются.

Пфффффф....

Comment: Ну да, 1 исходный, порождено 5, у alexlz более точная формулировка)

Answer (score 0):

1 итерация. 0 && (0 == 1), break не выполняется, процесс порождённ.

2 итерация. 0 && (1 == 1), break не выполняется, процесс порожден

3 итерация. 0 && (2 == 1), break не выполняется, процесс порождён, выход из цикла

*Итого, 3 порождённых + 1 родительский, наверно :)
P.S я не знаю что делает fork(); в дебрях и под Linux не пишу, только что прочитал в сети.*

Comment: fork -- дублирует процесс. Возвращая pid нового родителю и 0 потомку.

Comment: я не учёл что и в порождённых процессах будут порождаться новые.